# Geocode me and write address on input before validate

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geocoding

I found a lot of plugins that allow geolocation and display on a map, but I want something different.

I would like to geocode when you come on page with option "do you want to be geolocated?"
If the user says yes, I want to take the address and put it in `<input type="text" id="xxx">`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` and [Google's reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)?

Comment: i try function GoogleGeocode() and function ReverseGoogleGeocode() etc.. i dont know how i can recover address and display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I accepted the challenge, and I've just written an implementation.

Here's [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHg3P/), that looks like this:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            label
            {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function get_location()
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geocode, handle_error);
            }

            function geocode(position)
            {
                var latlong = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                else if(window.ActiveXObject)
                    var request = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                request.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlong + "&sensor=true", true);
                request.send();

                request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
                    {
                        var address = eval("(" + request.responseText + ")");
                        document.getElementById("address").value = address.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + " " + address.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
                        document.getElementById("city").value = address.results[0].address_components[6].long_name;
                        document.getElementById("county").value = address.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
                        document.getElementById("postcode").value = address.results[0].address_components[5].long_name;
                        document.getElementById("country").value = address.results[0].address_components[4].long_name;
                    }
                }
            }

            function handle_error(err)
            {
                switch(err.code)
                {
                    case 1: /* PERMISSION_DENIED */ break;
                    case 2: /* POSITION_UNAVAILABLE */ break;
                    case 3: /* TIMEOUT */ break;
                }
                alert("Error " + err.code);
            }

            window.onload = get_location;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="address">Street address: </label><input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
        <label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
        <label for="county">County: </label><input type="text" id="county" name="county"><br>
        <label for="postcode">Postcode: </label><input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"><br>
        <label for="country">Country: </label><input type="text" id="country" name="country">
    </body>
</html>
```

Feel free to ask if you want any code clarifying!

I will write a more thorough breakdown of the code and various parameters tomorrow; time for bed!

Comment: fabulous !!! But it doesn't work when i try you're fiddle lol :D, the input stay empty

Comment: this works perfectly, at my home place geocode is disabled. Thx a lot !